# Why does Firestore return all records on my where query

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query my collection on name:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
    print(searchString)
    db.collection("Coins").order(by: "name").whereField("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchString)
        .getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {

                var coins:[CryptoCompareService.Coin] = []
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let coin = try! FirestoreDecoder().decode(CryptoCompareService.Coin.self, from: document.data())

                    coins.append(coin)
                }  

            }
    }
```

My collection item looks like such:

[image]

I am sending text but it always returns all the items in the collection. Any thoughts?

EDIT: It looks as though it is weird in how it handles case sensitivity. When I typed in say, Eth, it gives me all records, but when I type in "eth" it gives me 11 records. Which is also wrong. Or at least I don't understand how the heck in searches.

Comment: The documentation shows that the `whereField` filter comes **before** the `order`.  I haven't tried querying the other way around to see what happens

Comment: Okay, thought that would work, but it didn't.  :-(

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the "name" field is a way to identify each entry, try to change the type of data you store in name to **Integers** instead of strings (or you can just add another field to store a unique number of the entry and perform queries based on that). I believe when you use that isGreaterThanOrEqualTo it is comparing the ascii code of each character instead of its real value or the lexicological order of characters, thats why you are getting different results when writing "Eth" or "eth".

In ascii code "E" is not the same as "e".

Comment: Do you mean to convert the text into a string of integers? This is definitely a shortcoming on this particular tech. They want me to integrate a text search engine, via cloud functions, etc..... very, very hackish to me.

Comment: I meant that you store the "007" for example as an integer so when it is stored it will look like this: 
`name: 7`
notice there are not quotation marks surrounding the number 7. again I am not sure why this is happening to you, I haven't used firestorm, but I am assuming that it is comparing ascii codes

Comment: just to be sure. You are trying to query names that has a number "007" in this case greater than a certain number ? for example all names that have numbers greater than 5 ?